# Get count of records matching filters Laravel pagination

Tags: laravel-5, filter, pagination, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I have few filters on the view page and want to show the count that matches the given conditions. Like on the product search result I have `Free Shipping` filter. I need the count of records matching my filters in the total record not just in the current page.

Explanation:
Suppose In the result set I have 100 records with pagination 20/page, 40 of them has free_shipping = 1. I want to show like `Free Shipping(40)`. Currently, I do `$products->where('free_shipping', 1)->count()` but this gives me the result matching only in viewed records.

How can I get the total number of matching records regardless of pagination?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the content of `$products`? How do you create it?

Comment: I didn't get your question. I've added some explanation to my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean `Product::where('free_shipping', 1)->count();`?

Comment: Yes, The `$products` hold the result set of `Product` model. I want the total number of products that offer free shipping but the `count()` gives the number in the current page, not the all possible results.

Comment: That's what my suggested code does (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: Yes. `Product::where('free_shipping', 1)->count();` give the correct value but I want to get value with the results. There are more filters that need other count values. So it'll end up clumsy by running too many queries just for the counts. Is there any way to use aggregates to do that?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

if Laravel Pagination is used then you can use the `total()` method.

Example : 
`$products->total();`